# Is it possible to use a windows 7 disk image (.vhd)) to boot into Hyper-v on a windows 10 system?

Tags: windows-10, windows-7, hyper-v

As the question states, I am trying to boot a windows 7 image, into Hyper-V on a Windows 10 Enterprise/Pro Ideally I will need to install on both types, the one I am working on is a Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 1909 system.

The disk image was made using Microsoft's built in back up system, in order to protect the important data located on the computer it was originally on, and is located on a USB 2.0 Drive

I have taken the image, and used it as the "Use existing virtual Hard Disk" option with Generation 1 (it is a vhd, not vhdx) virtual machine during set up. I have tried both on the usb drive and a copy I made to the HDD, to get this to boot. Regrettably I keep getting the error :

"Boot Failure. Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device"

When I created the backup file, it created both the recovery partition and the OS partition as .vhd files. I have verified that the file I am using is in fact the OS partition, by mounting it temporarily on the main computer.

Has anyone ever solved this problem before?

Answer (score 3):

VHD created using Windows Backup doesn't contain boot partition it only contains data. It could be mounted to migrate data to a new VM for example. You will need to use P2V tools such as StarWind V2V/P2V Converter to create a proper VHD/VHDX.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter